# Windows で Bitnami Redmine Stack を用い，1つの Apache サーバーで複数の Redmine を立ち上げたい

Tags: redmine, bitnami

最近，Redmine を触り始めたばかりの者です．
Redmine の少人数でのローカル環境での運用を考えております．

Windows で Bitnami Redmine Stack を用い，
1つの Apache サーバーで複数の Redmine を立ち上げたいと考えておりますが，
方法がわからなかったため質問させてください．

例として，

- 1つ目のRedmine:  http://127.0.0.1:80/redmine
- 2つ目のRedmine:  http://127.0.0.1:80/redmine02

という状態にしたいです．
可能なのでしょうか？

以下を参考にさせていただき一通り行いましたが，
http://127.0.0.1:80/redmine02 へアクセスすると，
元の http://127.0.0.1:80/redmine に接続されてしまっているようで，
理想とする動作ができませんでした．

参考:
一台のサーバー上でredmineを複数動かしてみる | 壁に向かって….
https://blog.fourthgate.jp/?p=1226

ご教授お願いいたします．

Comment: 複数立ち上げることも可能だと思いますが、Redmineには「プロジェクト」という単位で区切る機能があるので、管理の手間やパフォーマンスを考えるとこちらの方が簡単です。あえて複数のRedmineを立ち上げたい理由は何かありますか？

Comment: 古いので今も適用できるか不明ですが。[複数 Redmine を1ドメインでホストする](https://qiita.com/yteraoka/items/72b111e69511f254f97e)、[1台のホストの上で、複数のRedmineを立ち上げる方法。](http://gatolynx.blog100.fc2.com/blog-entry-322.html)、[同一PCで二つRedmineを動かす](http://daybreaksnow.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/04/11/183258) とか、少し方法は違いますが VirtualHost で作るとか。[イントラ環境向け複数Redmine構築メモと使用プラグイン一覧](https://qiita.com/crosspointst/items/33f0313e14b2c7b3595a)、[Apache のバーチャルホストで Redmine を動作させる 〜 CentOS6](https://easyramble.com/setup-redmine-with-apache-virtualhost.html)

Comment: @kunif `bitnami`を使用している点を考慮すべきかと思います。

Comment: @cubick さん，コメントありがとうございます．まだイメージが未熟な状態なのは確かです．一応プロジェクト機能は把握しておりますが，ひとつの可能性として確認したいと考えている程度です．また，全く関連のない複数のプロジェクトをRedmineで運用する場合に，1つのRedmineで運用することに違和感を感じております．

Comment: @cubick♦さん、確かにそうした条件の知識が無かったので頭にありませんでした。cubick♦さんの言う「プロジェクト」関連だと、この記事あたりが参考になりそうですか。[Redmine(プロジェクト管理ソフト)を導入してみた](https://k-1blog.com/design/web/post-3485/)

Comment: @kunif さん，色々とありがとうございます．私も色々と参考にさせていただき，一通りの機能に触ったり、2つ目のDBを作成することまでは試みましたが出来ていない状態です．[Redmine(プロジェクト管理ソフト)を導入してみた](https://k-1blog.com/design/web/post-3485/) に記載されているようなことは一通り触ってみております．
[複数 Redmine を1ドメインでホストする](https://qiita.com/yteraoka/items/72b111e69511f254f97e) を拝見したところ，Cookie関連の設定を何もしていないことに気づきましたので試してみようと思います．

Comment: 一応，動作確認が出来ました．色々変更してしまっているので，後ほど落ち着いた際に，この場に手順をご報告したいと思います．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

※同様の内容を qiita にも投稿しております．
https://qiita.com/SKYS/items/8197ebc19d85954e7688

※記事内にリンクを8個以上表示できなかったため，参考にさせていただいたサイトは別途投稿いたします．

---

## はじめに

Windows で Bitnami Redmine Stack を用い，1つの Apache サーバーで複数の Redmine を立ち上げた際のノートを，例と共に以下に記します．

私が調べた限りでは同様のことを行っている例が見当たらず，色々と調べて辿り着いた結果となります．
他に良い方法がありましたら，また，間違いがありましたら，ご指摘いただけましたら幸いです．

### 目標

- 1つ目のRedmine: http://127.0.0.1/redmine
- 2つ目のRedmine: http://127.0.0.1/redmine02

という構成にします．
（2つ目が作れれば，3つ目以降も同様に作れると思います．）

### 環境

- Windows 10 64bit Ver.1809
- Bitnami Redmine Stack 3.4.6-5

  - ダウンロード直リンク: https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/redmine/3.4.6-5/bitnami-redmine-3.4.6-5-windows-installer.exe
- 前提

  - Bitnami Redmine Stack が`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\`にインストールされていることを想定しています．
  - Bitnami Redmine Stack が1つしかインストールされていない（デフォルトのポートを使用している）ことを想定しています．

## 手順概要

1. Redmine App ディレクトリのコピー
2. Apache Conf ファイルの設定
3. URL および Cache の設定
4. データベースの設定
5. Thinサーバーのサービスへの登録
6. 動作確認

## 1. Redmine App ディレクトリのコピー

`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\`下に保存されている`redmine`ディレクトリを，名前を`redmine02`として，同ディレクトリ下にまるごとコピーします．

```
copy C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine\  C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine02\
```

[image: image.png]

コマンドで書きましたが，エクスプローラー上でコピーしても問題ないです．

## 2. Apache Conf ファイルの設定

#### 変更が必要なファイル

変更が必要なファイルは以下の4つです．

- C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apache2\conf\bitnami\

  - bitnami-apps-prefix.conf
- C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine02\conf\

  - httpd-app.conf
  - httpd-prefix.conf
  - httpd-vhosts.conf

#### bitnami-apps-prefix.conf

以下の1行を追記

```
Include "C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

#### httpd-app.conf

以下の通り，書き換え

- `/redmine` -> `/redmine02`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]

<Directory "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/htdocs/public">
    Options -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

    Include "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/conf/banner.conf"
</Directory>
```

#### httpd-prefix.conf

以下の通り，書き換え

- `/redmine` -> `/redmine02`
- `balancer://redminecluster` -> `balancer://redminecluster02`
- `127.0.0.1:3001` -> `127.0.0.1:3003`
- `127.0.0.1:3002` -> `127.0.0.1:3004`

```
ProxyPass /redmine02 balancer://redminecluster02
ProxyPassReverse /redmine02 balancer://redminecluster02

<Proxy balancer://redminecluster02>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3003/redmine02
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3004/redmine02
</Proxy>

Include "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

#### httpd-vhosts.conf

以下の通り，書き換え

- `/redmine` -> `/redmine02`
- `127.0.0.1:3001` -> `127.0.0.1:3003`
- `127.0.0.1:3002` -> `127.0.0.1:3004`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.example.com
    ServerAlias www.redmine.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/htdocs/public"
    <Directory "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/htdocs/public">
        Options -MultiViews
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://redminecluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
    <Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3003
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3004
    </Proxy>

    Include "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName redmine.example.com
    ServerAlias www.redmine.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/htdocs/public"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/conf/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/conf/certs/server.key"
    <Directory "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/htdocs/public">
        Options -MultiViews
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://redminecluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
    <Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3003
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3004
    </Proxy>

    Include "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

## 3. URL および Cache の設定

#### 変更が必要なファイル

- C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine\htdocs\config

  - additional_environment.rb
- C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine02\htdocs\config

  - additional_environment.rb
  - configuration.yml

#### additional_environment.rb

以下の通り，書き換えと追記を行う

- `/redmine` -> `/redmine02`

追記部分について，元は`application.rb`に記載があるが，
`application.rb`は通常変更してはならないとのこと．
参考: [サブディレクトリ運用の複数の Redmine で別の Redmine にアクセスすると勝手にログアウトするのを防ぐ - suer のブログ](https://suer.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/03/08/171746)

\apps\redmine\htdocs\config\additional_environment.rb

```
# 追記
config.session_store :cookie_store,
    :key => '_redmine_session',
    :path => config.action_controller.relative_url_root
```

\apps\redmine02\htdocs\config\additional_environment.rb

```
# 書き換え
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/redmine02'

# 追記
config.session_store :cookie_store,
    :key => '_redmine_session',
    :path => config.action_controller.relative_url_root
```

#### configuration.yml

93行目を書き換え

```
# 93行目
autologin_cookie_path: Redmine::Utils.relative_url_root
```

## 4. データベースの設定

### 4-1. データベース設定ファイルの編集

#### 変更が必要なファイル

- C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine02\htdocs\config

  - database.yml

#### database.yml

以下の通り書き換え
※password は「7dd1f5f7ed」となっています．適当に置き換えてください．
※ユーザー名は「bitnami02」としました．適当に置き換えてください．

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: bitnami02_redmine02
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: bitnami02
  password: 7c0e82d67b
  encoding: utf8
  port: 3306
```

### 4-2. データベース作成

※password，ユーザー名は`database.yml`で設定したものと同じものを使用する必要があります．

#### MySQL を稼働させる

[image: image.png]

#### コンソールを立ち上げ

`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\use_redmine.bat`を実行

#### ログイン

`mysql -u root -p`
※[bitnami redmine stack インストール時に使用したパスワード]を続けて入力

```
C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.42 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

#### データベース作成

`CREATE DATABASE bitnami02_redmine02 CHARACTER SET utf8;`

#### ユーザー作成

`CREATE USER 'bitnami02'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '7dd1f5f7ed';`

#### 権限の設定

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bitnami02_redmine02.* TO 'bitnami02'@'localhost';`

#### 終了

`quit`

### 4-3. データベース設定反映

#### セッションストア秘密鍵の生成

`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\use_redmine.bat`を実行してコンソールを立ち上げ，以下の通り入力．

```
cd apps\redmine02\htdocs
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
```

#### マイグレーション

引き続き，以下の通りマイグレーションを実施

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

## 5. Thinサーバーのサービスへの登録

### 5-1. 設定ファイルの編集-1

#### 変更が必要なファイル

- C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\

  - serviceinstall.bat
  - servicerun.bat

#### serviceinstall.bat

以下の通り，書き換え

- `/redmine` -> `/redmine02`
- `redmineThin1` -> `redmineThin102`
- `redmineThin2` -> `redmineThin202`
- `3001` -> `3003`
- `3002` -> `3004`

```
@echo off
rem -- Check if argument is INSTALL or REMOVE

if not ""%1"" == ""INSTALL"" goto remove

"C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02\scripts\winserv.exe" install "redmineThin102" -start auto "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\ruby\bin\ruby.exe" "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02\htdocs\bin\thin" start -p 3003 -e production -c "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/htdocs" -a 127.0.0.1 --prefix /redmine02
net start redmineThin102 >NUL
"C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02\scripts\winserv.exe" install "redmineThin202" -start auto "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\ruby\bin\ruby.exe" "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02\htdocs\bin\thin" start -p 3004 -e production -c "C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02/htdocs" -a 127.0.0.1 --prefix /redmine02

net start redmineThin202 >NUL

goto end

:remove
rem -- STOP SERVICE BEFORE REMOVING

net stop redmineThin102 >NUL

"C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02\scripts\winserv.exe" uninstall "redmineThin102"

net stop redmineThin202 >NUL
"C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5/apps/redmine02\scripts\winserv.exe" uninstall "redmineThin202"

:end
exit
```

#### servicerun.bat

以下の通り，書き換え

- `/redmine` -> `/redmine02`
- `redmineThin1` -> `redmineThin102`
- `redmineThin2` -> `redmineThin202`

```
@echo off
rem START or STOP Apache Service
rem --------------------------------------------------------
rem Check if argument is STOP or START

if not ""%1"" == ""START"" goto stop

net start redmineThin102

net start redmineThin202

goto end
:stop

net stop redmineThin102

net stop redmineThin202

:end
exit
```

### 5-2. 設定ファイルの編集-2

#### 変更が必要なファイル

- C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\

  - serviceinstall.bat
  - servicerun.bat
  - properties.ini

#### serviceinstall.bat

`\redmine`の部分を`\redmine02`に変更して行を複製する．

1箇所目

```
:: 元々存在
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\serviceinstall.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\serviceinstall.bat INSTALL)

:: ↑の次の行に以下を追記
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\serviceinstall.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\serviceinstall.bat INSTALL)
```

2箇所目

```
:: 元々存在
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\serviceinstall.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\serviceinstall.bat)

:: ↑の次の行に以下を追記
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\serviceinstall.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\serviceinstall.bat)
```

#### servicerun.bat

`\redmine`の部分を`\redmine02`に変更して複製する．

1箇所目

```
:: 元々存在
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\servicerun.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\servicerun.bat START)

:: ↑の次の行に以下を追記
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\servicerun.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\servicerun.bat START)
```

2箇所目

```
:: 元々存在
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\servicerun.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine\scripts\servicerun.bat STOP)

:: ↑の次の行に以下を追記
if exist C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\servicerun.bat (start /MIN C:\Bitnami\REDMIN~1.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\servicerun.bat STOP)
```

#### properties.ini

以下を追記

```
[Thin_redmine3]
thin_server_port=3003
thin_unique_service_name=redmineThin102
[Thin_redmine4]
thin_server_port=3004
thin_unique_service_name=redmineThin202
```

### 5-3. サービスの開始

※管理者権限が必要

```
C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\apps\redmine02\scripts\serviceinstall.bat INSTALL
```

`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.6-5\manager-windows.exe`を開き直すと，`redmineThin3`と`redmineThin4`が追加されていることを確認できると思います．
[image: image.png]

## 6. 動作確認

以上で，設定は完了です．

成功していれば，サーバーを再起動することで，それぞれのアドレスにアクセスできるようになります．

- http://127.0.0.1/redmine
- http://127.0.0.1/redmine02

Comment: 参考にさせていただいたサイト一覧-1
| Bitnami Redmine Stack 3.4.6-5 取得方法
    - [Redmine 3.4.* installer - Redmine - Bitnami Community](https://community.bitnami.com/t/redmine-3-4-installer/63877)
| Redmine アプリ複製全般
    - [一台のサーバー上でredmineを複数動かしてみる | 壁に向かって….](https://blog.fourthgate.jp/?p=1226)
| Apache Conf ファイルの設定
    - [Apacheによる負荷分散構成 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Kazunori-Kimura/items/ac0ec57df751f25b2c06)
| Cache の設定
    - [サブディレクトリ運用の複数の Redmine で別の Redmine にアクセスすると勝手にログアウトするのを防ぐ - suer のブログ](https://suer.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/03/08/171746)

Comment: 参考にさせていただいたサイト一覧-2
| データベースの設定
    - [Bitnami Redmine StackのMySQL初期設定について](http://a1-style.net/redmine/mysql-setting/)
| Thinサーバーのサービスへの登録
    - [Windows版RedmineのレスポンスはThinを追加して改善](http://a1-style.net/redmine/add-redmine-thin/)
    - [Changing Redmine URL - Redmine - Bitnami Community](https://community.bitnami.com/t/changing-redmine-url/49533/2)